# Android button state not stored/remembered on back button

Tags: android, button, state

I have a problem with Android's Fragment states. I have a fragment with 3 seekbars in it. At the bottom of the fragment there is a button, with which you proceed to the next fragment (using a fragmenttransaction). Now, this 'next'-button is disabled when the fragment is first created. I want the user to first use the 3 seekbars before they can proceed to the next fragment. This all works fine. However, in some cases the user can go back to the previous question/fragment by using the back button. Unfortunatly, when I hit the back button the 'next'-button's state is set to disabled again. To me this is very strange because as far as I know Android should automatically store the state of the views. As a matter of fact: Android does store the state (position) of the seekbars.

Why does Android stores the state of the seekbars but not the state from the button? The button is disabled in XML, so I'm not changing it programmatically in the onCreate or something like that.

Anyone knows why Android can't remember the state (enabled/disabled) of the button? It's driving me nuts for days now...

*BTW: I did try to use the onSaveInstanceState method and store the button's state within the bundle, but the onSaveInstanceState() method is never even called (so the bundle is always empty in the onCreate!)*

**EDIT:**

A bit of my code. First, the way I enable the button (works fine):

```
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    seekBar.setTag(true);
}

public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {      
    if (happyBar.getTag().equals(true) && relaxedBar.getTag().equals(true) && awakeBar.getTag().equals(true)) {
        nextButton.setEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

And this is the way I transit to the next fragment:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
ft.replace(R.id.fragmentcontainer, fragment);
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();
```

The buttons initial state is set to enabled=false in the XML. I do have to say that according to Eclipse the button's enabled XML-property is deprecated but I read on the internet that is a bug because it isn't deprecated at all. That's why I keep on using it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: where are you enabling the button?

Comment: in the onStopTrackingTouch() method implemented by OnSeekBarChangeListener. The enabling works fine, otherwise I couldn't proceed to the next fragment. When I return back however, I want the button to still be enabled, but somehow Android sets the state the disabled again.

Comment: I have not worked with fragments but could it be something about disabling noHistory ?

if u dont resolve you could save the state of the button in sharedPreferences

Comment: can you post the code. logic works fine..

Comment: I take it you are setting the fragments to the back stack?

Comment: Yes I add them to the back stack. I do pass NULL as a string while adding the fragment to the backstack but that shouldn't be a problem (according to the docs). I know where the string is used for, but I never have to use it in that way so that's why I keep it NULL.